# Relative height of DIV on Window Resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

OK, so here's my issue :

- I've built a website using Twitter bootstrap.
- At the very bottom of each page, I'm having a fixed footer (`navbar-fixed-bottom`).
- Now, above that I'm having a DIV - however, I want that DIV's height set so that it fits just right *above* the footer, not behind it, but like 30px above - no matter what the window size.

How is that possible?

Comment: please provide us a fiddle

Comment: Add a 30px padding to the bottom of the div and make it full height.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use margin-bottom :

```
margin-bottom: 60px;
```

Matching fiddle :
[Bootstrap Navbar JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7P6Uf/1/)